# How did the approximation $\left(1+\frac{h}{R}\right)^{-2} \approx 1-\frac{2h}{R}$ come about?

Tags: approximation

In physics there is a formula calculate the variation in the acceleration due to gravity at a height, it is given by:

$$g=g_0\left(1+\frac{h}{R}\right)^{-2}$$

But it is approximated as $$g=g_0\left(1-\frac{2h}{R}\right)$$

Some how the terms in the brackets are almost equal could anyone show why ?

Comment: binomial series

Comment: $h<<R$ so, $\frac{h}{R} <<1$. Use [binomial approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_approximation#:~:text=The%20binomial%20approximation%20is%20useful,be%20real%20or%20complex%20numbers.)

Comment: In general, the binomial (or Taylor) series tells us that $(1+h)^a=1+ah+O((ah)^2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For small $\frac hR$, ignore the terms of $(\frac hR)^2$ below

$$\left(1+\frac{h}{R}\right)^{-2} 
= \frac1{1+\frac{2h}{R}+( \frac{h}{R})^2}
\approx  \frac1{1+\frac{2h}{R}}
= \frac{1-\frac{2h}{R}}{1-(\frac{2h}{R})^2}
\approx 1-\frac{2h}{R}
$$

Answer (score 4):

Even without knowing the binomial series or approximations, this can be shown via geometric series:  recall $$f(z) = \frac{1}{1-z} = 1 + z + z^2 + \cdots, \quad |z| < 1,$$ so that $$\frac{1}{(1-z)^2} = (1 + z + z^2 + \cdots )^2 = 1 + 2z + 3z^2 + \cdots.$$  Then with the choice $z = -h/R$, we have $$\left(1 + \frac{h}{R}\right)^{-2} = 1 - \frac{2h}{R} + \frac{3h^2}{R^2} - \cdots.$$  The approximation improves as $h/R \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Reacall binomial expansion for negative index as
$$(1+x)^{-2}=1-2x+\frac{-2(-3)}{2!}x^2+\frac{-2(-3)(-4)}{3!}x^3+...$$
When $x<<1$, then by retaining first two terms we wet the approximation:
$$(1+x)^{-2}\approx 1-2x.$$

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this is not inherently different from the other answers posted, but you can get this from the simple Taylor expansion:
$$
f(x) \approx f(0) + x f'(0),\qquad\text{where}\qquad f(x)= (1 + x)^{-2}.
$$
This gives $f(x) \approx 1 - 2x$ or, with $x = h/R$,
$$
\left(1 + \frac h R\right)^{-2}
\approx
1 - \frac{2h}{R}.
$$
By Taylor's theorem with remainder, the error is at most $3h^2 / R^2$ (i.e., the quadratic term in the series expressions give by other users).

Answer (score 1):

We want to show that for small $|x|$,
$$(1+x)^{-2}\approx 1-2x$$
Equivalently,
$$(1+x)^2(1-2x)\approx 1$$
Now,
$$\begin{align}
&(1+x)^2(1-2x)\\
&=(1+2x+x^2)(1-2x)\\
&=1+2x+x^2-2x-4x^2-2x^3\\
&=1-3x^2-2x^3\\
\end{align}$$

When $x$ is sufficiently small, we can ignore the $x^2$ and $x^3$ terms.

Also,
$$\frac1{(1+x)^2} 
= \frac{1-2x}{1-3x^2-2x^3}$$
Once again, for small $x$ we can ignore the higher powers of $x$, so the denominator of the RHS is very close to $1$.

---

If we look at the graphs of these functions, we can see that the line $y=1-2x$ is tangent to the curve $y=(1+x)^{-2}$ at $(0, 1)$.

[image: graphs of 1/(x+1)^2 & 1-2x]

So the slope of the curve at $(0, 1)$ is $-2$. When you learn calculus, you will learn how to find the slope of a tangent at a point on a curve. But here's a "sneak preview". Let's find the slope $m$ of the line through $(0, 1)$ and $(x, 1/(1+x)^2)$ for some small $x$.
$$m=\frac{1-1/(1+x)^2}{x}$$
$$m=\frac{-2-x}{(1+x)^2}$$
As $x$ gets close to $0$, $m$ gets close to $-2$.

---

FWIW, we can find the series

$$\frac1{(1+x)^2}=1-2x+3x^2-4x^3+5x^4-6x^5+\dots$$
which is valid for $|x|<1$, using [polynomial long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division).

$$\begin{align}
&\underline{1-2x+3x^2-\dots}\\
1+2x+x^2)&1\\
&\underline{1+2x+x^2}\\
&-2x-x^2\\
&\underline{-2x-4x^2-2x^3}\\
&3x^2+2x^3\\
&\underline{3x^2+6x^3+3x^4}\\
&-4x^3-3x^4\\
\end{align}$$
Etc.

And we can verify it by multiplication:

$$\begin{array}{r|rrrrrrr} 
1 & 1 & -2x & +3x^2 & -4x^3 & +5x^4 & -6x^5 & \dots\\
2x &  & 2x & -4x^2 & +6x^3 & -8x^4 & +10x^5 & \dots\\
x^2 &  &  & x^2 & -2x^3 & +3x^4 & -4x^5 & \dots\\ \end{array}$$